# Constantly failing to create the Java virtual machine on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

I just installed : "[FishStatJ, a Java-based desktop application,](http://www.fao.org/fishery/statistics/software/fishstatj/en#1)"

Download is fine, installing is fine but when I try to use the program I get this message:

> Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.

I have done everything that I can think of

- Updated java
- got the developers kit part from their home page to see if it would help
- cleaned up the computer and etc

And my computer is almost new, it's a IBM think station with up to date Windows 7, so the hardware should not be a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
*sorry for the bad spelling, English is my 2nd language.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183038/every-java-program-crashes-with-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121239/failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine---after-new-install-on-xp

Comment: You can try adding `-debug` to the `java` invocation (ahead of other parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Provided page seems to says it only supports 32-bit. If you are using a 64-bit system, it will not work.

Comment: yes. I am running windows 7 in 64-bit. but isn´t every thing that works in 32 suppose to work in 64?

Comment: thanks I see that the only way I can run this program on this computer is by installing virtualbox. thank you.